# How do I declare the height without fixed value(px)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently studying HTML/CSS/DOM and I am a begginer. I tried to make an Instagram main page for practicing and improving my level. I will share my code, so you can understand what I'm trying to do!
This is HTML code

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}

@font-face {
  font-family: instagramFont;
  src: url("./westagram.ttf") format("opentype");
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.wrapper .nav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #dbdbdb;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  /*포지션 여러개 썼을때 우선순위 설정 인덱스값이 클수록 우선순위*/
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .nav .logo {
  font-family: instagramFont;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.search-box {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 28px;
}

.wrapper .nav .icons {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.wrapper .main {
  position: relative;
  /*포지션을 쓰면 위치 조정 top left right bottom*/
  top: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 900px;*/
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  right: 5px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 660px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
}

. .wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi {
  position: relative;
  /*width: 97%;*/
  /*height: 100px;*/
  /*background-color: black;*/
}

.identi {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi .selfi {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi .id {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi .fa {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .pic {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /*top: 10px;*/
  height: 65%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .show-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .comment {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9%;
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .name {
  /*margin-left: 40px;*/
  /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
}

.wrapper .main .main-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#compass {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

#heart {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

#my-page {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Westagram Main Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- header : segmantic tag -->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
      <p class="logo"> Westagram </p>
      <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search" , style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
      <div class="icons">
        <img id="compass" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/explore.png">
        <img id="heart" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/heart.png">
        <img id="my-page" src=" https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/profile.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="feeds">
        <div class="article">
          <div class="identi">
            <img class="selfi" src="about.png">
            <span class="id"> Jiwan Jeon </span>
            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="pic">
          </div>

          <div class="show-box">
          </div>

          <div class="comment">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

According to the CSS file, I declare the height of each section for checking those sections in the right position. Based on my knowledge, If I delete the height, it would be automatically adjusted height(I mean Depending on the size of the screen window, the horizontal/vertical height will increase or decrease.) This is what was expected. However, the main and the height of the others is fixed... Could you help me out with this problem? I struggling with it the whole day :(

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Use percentages like `10%` or base it off of viewport height like `10vh` or viewport width `10vw`. Learn more about [`CSS Length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Answer (score 0):

You can use vh (view height) ,em ,rem or percentage.

Example:

height: 120px;

height: 10em;

height: 75%;